# Give name of each index array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I got a multidimensional array like this, it is a result of some calculation:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0.0415
                [1] => 0.083
                [2] => 0.083
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0.0325
                [1] => 0.041
                [2] => 0.025
             )
        [1] => Array
             (
                [0] => 0.076
                [1] => 0.005
                [2] => 0.031
              )
     )
```

Is it possible to give a name of each index? The result that I expected is like this:

```
 Array
    (
        [A1] => Array
            (
                [C1] => 0.0415
                [C2] => 0.083
                [C3] => 0.083
            )
        [A2] => Array
            (
                [C1] => 0.0325
                [C2] => 0.041
                [C3] => 0.025
             )
        [A3] => Array
             (
                [C1] => 0.076
                [C2] => 0.005
                [C3] => 0.031
              )
     )
```

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, see `array_combine()`. But why `AX` and `CX` for the subArrays?!

Comment: @Rizier123 err.. because that's the name what i wanted? :/ well, thank you anyway.. i'll try it.

Comment: there is no duplicate key number in array!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with foreach loop.

```
$b=array();
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $new_key='A'.$k;
        $new_array= array();
         foreach ($v as $k2 => $val) {
           $kkk = 'C'.$k2;
           $new_array[$kkk]=$val;
         } 
        $b[$new_key]=$new_array;
}
```